# Information in Filtrations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, information-theory

Is the “information” kept track of by filtrations the same as information-theoretic “information”?

If not, is there some way the two concepts can be reconciled?

Comment: Filtration is about information from measure theory point of view, it increases with time as it is a stream of growing sigma-algebras, information theory needs probability to take into account the weight of information in a metric such as entropy. If you want to add a metric to the filtration in the spirit of information theory you have to put a probability space on it (like a Wiener measure) the thing is that is complex matter I believe to make a metric with a meaning, well maybe this exists but I am not aware of those kinds of approaches. Best regards